# "References to interface static methods are allowed only at source level 1.8" or above when I already have a 1.8 JRE

Tags: java, eclipse

I got this error when trying to call a static method in a Maven project that I'm working on. I thought that this error seemed odd, as I'm using 1.8.

[image: Eclipse says I'm already using a 1.8 JRE]

Additionally, I added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

Neither solution seemed to work, and I'm puzzled as to why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse's maven integration is somewhat wonky at times. Check the Eclipse project properties, and ensure that the source and target levels are set to 1.8 there, too.

Comment: @Taschi-corporationsarebad Ahh, I forgot to check that! Doing this worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear, I've reposted it as an answer so you can accept it and mark the question as solved.

Comment: JRE level is irrelevant. You need a 1.8 JDK, and you need to set the source level in your project to 1.8 or higher in the IDE.

Comment: Simply right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._ and Eclipse will update the project according to the Java version set in the `pom.xml`. There is also a preference to do this automatically, but which is disabled by default.

Comment: @Taschi-corporationsarebad I leave it to you to answer the question (by undeleting and correcting your existing answer). I guess you misunderstood my comments. I'm here to help, just like you. There is no reason to fight me. The reason why I have not given an answer by my own is that I leave it up to you. So, please help to make Stack Overflow a welcome place for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> set Compiler compliance level to 1.8.

This fixed the problem for me.